# Mutithreading Issue With Scope Request of Bean

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, java-8, parallel-processing

Currently facing issue while using `Thread` and parallel stream for below code

```
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor

Future<List<Boolean>> resList = executor.submit(()->requestIds.parallelStream().map(id->completeTask(id)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            List<Boolean> resultList = resList.get();
```

Getting bean of scope request cannot be used/ thread exception. The method used in the stream is calling another method of a different class which is giving error for scope request.

```
Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

`RequestContextListener` is used in the Spring Boot application

Comment: Please add the proper error stacktrace and if you are using spring, please mention that.

Comment: added the error and it is spring boot application

Comment: Don't use request scoped beans in threads other then the one handling the request.

Comment: i can not change the scope of that bean as it is used in lot of another methods in the project

Comment: @user4886675 are you using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor object as spring bean or plain java object. ThreadPoolTaskExecutor also should be created as spring bean and should be present in spring applicationContext, something like this e.g.


    `@ Bean
    public TaskExecutor executorA() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }`

Comment: Using it as spring bean